# How to create an auto-respond email subscription form in 5 minutes?

Tags: forms

I am developing a splash screen as coming soon for my new website and want an email subscription form with auto-responding capabality. I can do this myself but I was pondering if there is any services out there to handle such email related activities or we should still do such things by ourselves?
Sorry if this sounds a rather old-school question but I have always done such things by myself and guess there should be a better way too ;)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a mailing list? You could always just use the tried-and-true [GNU Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html). It has auto-reply abilities.